# Best practice to use interface for different event handling

Tags: php, oop, events, design-patterns, interface

I have a common method i.e. onMessage that takes input from different clients ( Websocket client ).

Clients send different messages in a specific data format i.e.

```
{
    "event" : "init",
    "data" : {}
}
```

All this different messages are parsed by onMessage function.

Now i have a use case where based on event of message for e.g. if event is `init` publish something, if event is `heartbeat` publish something etc.

What's the most generic way so that event with different implementation can be added even later.

So far i have an idea that i have to use interfaces. What i'm doing is is i have a Interface called `EventInterface` with `publish`, `getName` method.

Then i created a class called `Init` that implements `EventInterface` and defines `publish` & `getName` method.

Now how do i connect my `onMessage` function with this different Event classes. This are type of different Event-listeners i believe.

Right now one solution that comes in my mind is to create class called `Events` that stores all the event Object i.e. Init class object, HeartBeat class object in an array.

So when i create object from Events and pass the `message` from onMessage method and call magic method it loops through event object array and matches name using `getName` method of the appropriate event classes and calls publish methods.

Idk if this is the best way to handle this use case. If this is okay way then is there anyway i can avoid manually adding objects to event object method of `Events` class? Or that's okay?

Comment: _"is to create class called Events that stores all the event Object"_
& _"it loops through event object array and matches name using getName method of the appropriate event classes"_ - this sounds a lot like the Observer pattern. Do mean this?

Comment: Yes so events class has all the events object and a magic method will watch out which object method to instantiate. It just doesn't feel clean since everytime a new event class is creates its object has to be instantiated in events class too? Is this a right way though?

Comment: It's hard to answer, because all I can do is imagine the architect of your software. But objects in arrays just point to the object in the heap, because they only store the reference. So I guess you only have to instantiate the object once and set the reference in the array of the objects you have.

Comment: It would be better for any of us if you supply a demo (pseudo code, whatever ..) of how you think it would work in your situation (or how you think it _might_ fit your needs). Its far easier to enhance a demo and point to possible flaws than hypothetically create a scenario in which it _might_ work ..